# Designing a pocket Kusarigama

Tags: weapons, engineering

Well, this is a simple question. This is a Kusarigama:

[image]

I like exotic weapons so I want to reduce it to pocket size but without rendering the weapon useless. Furthermore the weapon needs a folding mechanism to carry it more comfortably. I was inspired by [this video that shows the opposite](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0B2VUD6bnH0) (a giant butterfly knife).

**What would a pocket kusarigama look like?**

Comment: A problem which should be addressed is the problem that pocket knives have - They make terrible weapons because the joint is an awful weak point, which very often gives way. The way this weapon is designed would put a lot of stress on the obvious location for a hinge, which could easily cause it to break. I'm not saying it's impossible, but some mechanism should be involved to counteract this issue

Comment: Another problem with shrinking such a weapon is that it will reduce its mass. But since it is meant to be thrown, reducing its mass will reduce also its inertia, resulting in less effective projections.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of scaling down the kusirigama, perhaps your protagonist or antagonist should wear a trenchcoat or otherwise conceal the whole weapon as originally designed.

As Andon said in a comment, there are a lot of sections put under stress.  Range is another benefit of this weapon and making is pocket sized is going to make it really Batman-y.

Comment: +1 for answering "how to fit this into a pocket?" with "get bigger pockets".